# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_bank_balance(): #prompt for an intial bank balance
    balance = int(input("Enter an initial bank balance (dollars): "))
    return balance


def add_to_bank_balance(balance):   #prompt for amount to add to balance
    wager = int(input("Enter a wager (dollars): "))
    return wager


def get_wager_amount():     #prompt for a wager on a particular roll
    wager = add_to_bank_balance
    return wager


def is_valid_wager_amount(wager, balance):      # checks that wager is less than or equal to balance
    if wager < balance:
        return is_valid_wager_amount(wager, balance)

def main(): 
    # plays the game 
    display_game_rules() 
    get_bank_balance() 
    add_to_bank_balance(balance) 
    get_wager_amount() 
    is_valid_wager_amount(wager, balance)
```

Comment: Where is `is_valid_wager_amount` called? Please post a full [mcve].

Comment: Your code is not complete, it's just a list of functions. Also, that error message comes with way more information. Please help us help you.

Comment: def main():    # plays the game
    display_game_rules()
    get_bank_balance()
    add_to_bank_balance(balance)
    get_wager_amount()
    is_valid_wager_amount(wager, balance)

Comment: Put it in the question...format it properly.....

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this website and format it

Comment: Where are `wager` and `balance` defined? You're calling `is_valid_wager_amount(wager, balance)`, but you don't have any assignments to a variable named `wager` or `balance`. There is more code you aren't showing.

Comment: I'm not sure what to assign them to, should they be assigned outside the functions??

Comment: There's no way you got that error by calling the code you called. The interpreter would have exploded earlier: like when you call `add_to_bank_balance(balance)` without properly defining `balance`.

Comment: Your `is_valid_wager_amount` function looks like it will hit a recursion depth limit as well. There's no modification to `wager` and `balance`, so if they satisfy the `if` statement, they always will and your code will error out

Comment: "I'm not sure how to use this website": well, welcome to Stack Overflow then! As you are experiencing problems, I'd suggest you *at least* read the introductory [tour] as it mentions the most important features (which is exactly why it was suggested when you first signed up). You may want to browse the [help] and read up on how to ask a good question and how to format posts.

Answer (score 2):

The interpreter is telling you *exactly* what the problem is. You can't compare two function objects using `<`. Your code has some extraneous issues I don't want to get in to, so let's consider a more minimal example of how you can get this error and how you can fix it.

Here's how you could get the `TypeError` you're getting:

```
def func1():
    return 1

def func2():
    return 2

if func1 < func2:
    print("All is well. 1 is less than 2.")
```

Slap this code into a file called `test.py` and run it in your shell:

```
PS C:\Users\matt\repos\kata\stack> python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    if func1 < func2:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'function'
```

This is the exact error you (somehow) got (although you're not showing your full code, because the code you've shown would cause a *different* error upon invoking `main()`).

**The problem:** `func1` is a function (and so is `func2`). In order to call it, you have to say `func1()`.

**The fix**:

```
# func1 -> func1() and func2 -> func2().
if func1() < func2():
    print("All is well. 1 is less than 2.")
```

then if you run it again with this change, you'll get the expected result:

```
PS C:\Users\matt\repos\kata\stack> python test.py
All is well. 1 is less than 2.
```

You may want to take a step back and read more about variables, functions, and Python fundamentals before writing your bank application.

HTH.